# Python: Combining two CSV files with header row and matched values with DictReader and DictWriter

Tags: python, csv

I am having a couple different issues with this script. The goal is straight-foward and I have found some similar examples but nothing to get this working quite yet.

1. Read in a base CSV file - this can vary with the field names and number of fields
2. Read in a secondary CSV file containing one ID that should have a match to the ID column in first file, plus a new ID
3. Create an output CSV file that contains the column headers from file 1 + column headers from file 2
4. Print the rows in the output file that are the entire row contents of the first file, plus the matched ID from the second file.

I'm struggling with how to properly create the header rows for the output file as well as how to include the whole row from the first file with the matched key from the second. I was able to get this to work with the reader, but needed to switch to DictReader to avoid hard-coding the column number as they can change.
Here is my attempt. Any help greatly appreciated!

Here are some example files:

Example File1:
[{'LEGACY_ID': '123', 'Random Column': 'Ignore Me but print me', 'Another Column': 'Ignore me too'}, 
{'LEGACY_ID': '1234', 'Random Column': 'Ignore Me but print me', 'Another Column': 'Ignore me too'} ... ]

Example File2:
[{'NEW_ID': 'abc', 'LEGACY_ID': '123'}, {'NEW_ID
': 'abcd', 'LEGACY_ID': '1234'} ... ]

Example output:
[{'LEGACY_ID': '123', 'Random Column': 'Ignore Me but print me', 'Another Column': 'Ignore me too', 'NEW_ID': 'abc'},
{'LEGACY_ID': '1234', 'Random Column': 'Ignore Me but print me', 'Another Column': 'Ignore me too', 'NEW_ID': 'abcd'} ... ]

```
import csv
import string
with open('legacyFile.csv', 'r') as in_leg, open('NewMapping.csv', 'r') as in_map, open('results.csv', 'wb') as out_res:
    c1 = csv.DictReader(in_leg, delimiter=',')
    c2 = csv.DictReader(in_map, delimiter=',') 
    print c1.fieldnames
    print c2.fieldnames
    #set headers and write header row to output file
    File1List = list(c1)
    File2List = list(c2)

    fieldnames = (str(c1.fieldnames) + str(c2.fieldnames)) 
    fieldnames = string.replace(fieldnames, '][', ', ')
    print (fieldnames)

    c3 = csv.DictWriter(out_res, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    c3.writeheader()

    print ' c3 ' + c3.fieldnames

    for File1Row in File1List:
        row = 1
        found = False
        print ('ID IS ' + File1Row['ID'])
        for File2Row in File2List:
            if File1Row['ID'] == File2Row['LEGACY_ID']:
                #need to write the entire File1Row to c3, PLUS the matched ID that is found
                #c3.writerow(File1Row + File2Row['NEW_ID'])
                print ('Found New ID of ' +  File2Row['NEW_ID'] + ' at row ' + str(row))
                found = True
                break
            row += 1
        if not found:
            #need to write the entire File1Row to c3, with null value for non-matching values
            print ('not found')


    in_leg.close()
    in_map.close()
    out_res.close()
```

Comment: provide a sample of input files & sample of output file.

Comment: See if you can condense your code to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this will help focus responses and shows that you have taken the time to think about what the core of the problem is.  Right now it is unclear where you're having trouble.

Comment: Aside: are you restricted to working with the stdlib?  If I'm understanding your goal, this is only a few lines in [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Comment: DSM: no, no restrictions... I'm just not familiar with pandas. I am new to python but will research it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully someone else will give an example based on your code for pure Python, but just to show you how you'd do this in [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org), using some mocked-up data:

```
import pandas as pd
df_old = pd.read_csv("legacyFile.csv")
df_new = pd.read_csv("NewMapping.csv")
df_merged = df_old.merge(df_new, left_on="ID", right_on="LEGACY_ID", how="outer")
df_merged.to_csv("combined.csv", index=False)
```

This code merges a DataFrame (kind of like a table, or an excel sheet) looking like

```
>>> df_old
   ID col1 col2
0   1    a    b
1   2    c    d
2   3    e    f
3   4    g    h
```

and one like

```
>>> df_new
   LEGACY_ID  NEW_ID  other_new_column
0          1     100             12.34
1          2     200             56.78
2          4     400             90.12
```

into an object

```
>>> df_merged
   ID col1 col2  LEGACY_ID  NEW_ID  other_new_column
0   1    a    b          1     100             12.34
1   2    c    d          2     200             56.78
2   3    e    f        NaN     NaN               NaN
3   4    g    h          4     400             90.12
```

and writes that out into a csv file.  Here I'm preserving row 3 which didn't have a match in the NewMapping file, but we could have just as easily kept only the ones which matched perfectly.

Comment: Wow, I would say that is much much easier. I already have a working output file, just need to make it more complex which I think I can do by continuing this script. Seems like it should have been that easy all along :) Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/)'s [csvjoin](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/scripts/csvjoin.html) command?

This will allow you to do

```
csvjoin --columns LEGACY_ID file1.csv file2.csv > new.csv
```

to get your new csv file

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on DSM's sample files, here's a pure Python solution. As it's quite lengthy, it's actually described with inline comments.

Given `legacyFile.csv`

```
ID  col1    col2
1   a   b
2   c   d
3   e   f
4   g   h
```

and `NewMapping.csv`

```
LEGACY_ID   NEW_ID  other_new_column
1   100 12.34
2   200 56.78
4   400 90.12
```

The solution:

```
import csv

with open('legacyFile.csv', 'r') as in_leg, open('NewMapping.csv', 'r') as in_map:
    the_map_reader = csv.DictReader(in_map, delimiter='\t')
    the_map = list(the_map_reader)      # read the whole map file in-memory, to execute searches

    # construct a dict, where LEGACY_ID is the key, and the value is the number of the row, in the map file
    legacy_ids = {row['LEGACY_ID']: row_number for (row_number, row) in enumerate(the_map)}

    # a simple dictionary used for output, when the map file has no such LEGACY_ID key
    missing_map_line = {key: '-' for key in the_map[0]}

    source = csv.DictReader(in_leg, delimiter='\t')

    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as out_res:
        # the output's columns are the combination of the source's fand the map's files
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_res, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=source.fieldnames + the_map_reader.fieldnames)
        # to create the header row
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in source:
            # get the number of the row in the map file, where ID == LEGACY_ID
            mapped_row_number = legacy_ids.get(row['ID'], -1)
            # if that row is present - use it, if not - the dummy line created above
            # at this step, if you don't want to output lines where the map file has no entry for this ID,
            # you could just call continue
            # if mapped_row_number == -1 : continue
            mapped_row = the_map[mapped_row_number] if mapped_row_number != -1 else missing_map_line

            # generate the resulting row
            result_line = row.copy()
            result_line.update(mapped_row)
            # and write it in the output file
            writer.writerow(result_line)
```

The result is:

```
ID  col1    col2    LEGACY_ID   NEW_ID  other_new_column
1   a   b   1   100 12.34
2   c   d   2   200 56.78
3   e   f   -   -   -
4   g   h   4   400 90.12
```

There is no way this solution is faster than pandas, especially on huge datasets.